# jQuery plugin not working after upgrade

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery version 1.10.2. Before I upgraded to this version, I was using jQuery version 1.4 or 1.8. I had to upgrade because I need many of the newest jQuery plugins. But I have a problem, **my jQuery to edit attributes doesn't work after upgrading to 1.10.2**. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ekerabat").click(function(){
        $("#kerja1").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#kerja2").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#kerja3").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#kerja4").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#hubungankerabat").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#namakerabat").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#statuskerabat").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#noindukerabat").attr("disabled",true);
        $("#unitkerabat").attr("disabled",true);
    });

    $("#dkerabat").click(function(){
        $("#kerja1").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#kerja2").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#kerja3").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#kerja4").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#hubungankerabat").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#namakerabat").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#statuskerabat").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#noindukerabat").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#unitkerabat").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
```

`ekerabat` and `dkerabat` are IDs of radio buttons, other is an `input` tag. When in old version, this works great, but after upgrading, even if I click one of radio buttons, nothing happens. I've Googled the issue and changed the code to use `.prop`s, but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know what should I use instead of `attr` in jQuery 1.10.2?

Comment: try giving it in `" "` like `$("#kerja1").attr("disabled","true");`

Comment: I don't get it, i have done that, right?

Comment: I think you haven't mentioned that you have done it in `" "`.. What I meant is give `"true"` inside `" "`. You have given it as `boolean` right - `true`? Try passing it as string in `" "`!!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, not mentioned that. Already try to give " ", still not working... other idea?

Comment: Any console errors??

Comment: it should be fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ra7cykj9/4/

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, I don't know why, but after copy paste Your code and edit it with my ID, now it works fine.... maybe I miss the "var disabled = this.id == 'ekerabat';". Thank You so much

Comment: @CrossVander can you share your previous code as it was

Comment: my code is in my question.. if You ask complete code, it's very long, about 323 line codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to fiddle from @Arun P Johnny

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ra7cykj9/4/

It solve the problem, maybe miss the  "var disabled = this.id == 'ekerabat';"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `attr()` use `prop()`. You can find complete information on below link:

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Please read the question completely!! **He has already mentioned he has tried that too**

Comment: That's right, already try prop, but doesn't works... is it removeProp for removing it right? if it yes, it doesn't works

Comment: To remove property .removeAttr() will work. But instead you can do like prop('disabled', false) which will enable the input or control.

Comment: not works... it solved by Arun... I don't know why but after copy paste his code and change with my input ID, all works fine...

Comment: He is also using prop() which I had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment but I'm not yet permitted to make comments.

I found an article that might help:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/adding-removing-disabled-attribute-to-submit-button

The key elements of syntax seem to be as follows.....have not tried it out which is why I would have made it a comment rather than an answer.

```
$("#kerja1").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("#kerja1").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");

<input type="submit" disabled="true">
```